# Weak linking popoverBackgroundViewClass to make it work in <5.0 IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, backwards-compatibility, weak-linking

Already checked this question: [Weak linking UIPopoverBackgroundView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428675/weak-linking-uipopoverbackgroundview)
and already read: http://www.marco.org/2010/11/22/supporting-older-versions-of-ios-while-using-new-apis#fnref:1

I have a custom PopoverBackgroundView declared in a .h and implemented in a .m file. Then, in just one file, I instantiate it like this

```
    self.settingsPopover.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBackgroundView class];
```

I´ve tried doing it like marco says in the link above:

```
if ([UIPopoverBackgroundView class] != nil) {
    self.settingsPopover.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [CustomPopoverBackgroundView class];
}
```

But I get the same launch error when I run in a 4.3 ipad simulator

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIPopoverBackgroundView
```

My base sdk is IOS 5.1, and my target deployment is 5.1 as well. Im using LLVM  compiler 4.0.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `respondsToSelector` with the relevant `UIPopoverController setBackgroundViewClass` method? Remember that properties automatically generate setter and getter methods that you can use in addition to the normal property syntax.

The reason why you're still getting linker errors is because you're still trying to call a method on that class, which doesn't exist.

If it's a case that the entire class doesn't exist, Apple recommends using `NSClassFromString(@"UIPopoverController")` and checking if the returned result is nil.

Comment: I havent any properties. The problem is that the app crashes before it can even reach my code. By setting UIkit as optional it works, but i dont want to do that

Comment: I know you haven't added any properties. What I mean is that by -using- a property in a class that doesn't exist, that's why it crashes. By verifying if the class exists via NSClassFromString before you use it, your application won't crash.